# How to get a file type without knowing its extension in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a file with no extension, and I need to know what kind of file is it. For example, given a path to a file, I want to know if the file is an image or a movie or a text file.

Is this possible?

For the record, this is for an iOs app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt there's an API for that... in which case you would need to open the file and examine its contents in an attempt to generate your best guess. Look for source to the *nix `file` command to review code that does what you're looking for.

Comment: Does the file not have an extension or do you not know what the extension is?

Comment: @Drewness I do have an extension, but it might be wrong. So I need to know if the extension matches the file type :). Thanks!

Comment: Ask NSFileManager to give you a list of files in the directory, and see which match the name you have.

Comment: @HotLicks I dont understand how that would help...

Comment: On iOS the relationship between file extension and content type is pretty firm.  If you know the extension you pretty much know the content type.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could be brute and just check for some characteristics in order of simplicity / likelihood, like:

1. Try to read it as text - do you get readable characters? Probably
   a text file.
2. Try to create an UIImage with the data - does is
   work? Then it's an image.
3. Try to put the file in a video player -
   does it play? Then it's a video.

:-)

Comment: jaja yes, that's what I'm doing at the moment and it is working. I just wanted to know if there is a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the file format. Some file formats are easily identifiable by examining the beginning of it. But some file types are only known by examining the file extension. So the only way to do this would be if you have a finite list of known formats that the file might be, and you find documentation on how to identify them.

Answer (score -1):

I would consider using [Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH202-CHDHIJDE). Since UTIs are organised into hierarchies, one possibility is to check whether the preferred UTI for a given file conforms to a top-level UTI, e.g. `public.image` for images or `public.movie` for movies and so on.

So for instance working on file extensions:

```
NSString *file = @"…"; // path to some file
CFStringRef fileExtension = (CFStringRef) [file pathExtension];
CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);

if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage)) NSLog(@"It's an image");
else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeMovie)) NSLog(@"It's a movie");
else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeText)) NSLog(@"It's text");

CFRelease(fileUTI);
```

If you have a MIME type instead of a file name extension, you can use `kUTTagClassMIMEType` instead of `kUTTagClassFilenameExtension`.

Comment: Already tried that, no luck.. found that solution before posting this question... remember I dont have the file extension. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Omer - BUT YOU CAN FIND THE EXTENSION IF YOU SCAN THE DIRECTORY.

Comment: @HotLicks nope, the file is sotred with no extension, i.e.: ../Documents/myFile -- you can also think the problem as if the extension of the file was not reliable of the file type.

Comment: There is a UNIX protocol for internal file identification that many files adhere to.  Basically within the first 10 characters or so is a 2-3 character ID.  I don't recall the particulars, though.

Comment: Others you can figure out.  JPEG, for instance will always start FF D8 FF.

Comment: WAV always starts with the characters "RIFF" followed by 4 bytes of data followed by "WAVE".

Comment: so what is the type equal doc/ docx. Thanks